# How do i add different background colors to multiple figcaptions?

Tags: css, background-color, figure

Hello dear stackoverflowers,

I'm working on a website where the ***background color*** of the ***figcaptions*** need to correspond with the background of the image it is on. So basically, multiple different background colors for multiple figcaptions. Is it possible to add an ID or class?

I've been searching the web far and wide without finding an answer, so here i am, adressing you brilliant people! This is what i have at the moment, which is pretty basic.

```
figcaption{ 
position: absolute; 
color: white; 
background: rgba(10,10,10,1); 
width:245px;
height:30%;
padding: 10px 20px; 

opacity: 100;
bottom: 0; 
left: -30%;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
-moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
-o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to the figcaption and apply background-color to that.

If you use the same class for the image and the figcaption they will have the same background colour - e.g.:

HTML

```
<img class="redbg">
<figcaption class="redbg">Caption</figcaption>
```

CSS

```
.redbg{ background:red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you can do that.

```
   figcaption{ 
    position: absolute; 
    color: white; 
    width:245px;
    height:30%;
    padding: 10px 20px; 

    opacity: 100;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: -30%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
        }
    .f1{
    background: rgba(10,10,10,1); //difference background 
    }
    .f2{
    background: rgba(10,10,1,1); //difference background
    }
    .f3{
    background: rgba(10,10,10,1); //difference background
    }
    ...
    .fn{
    ...
    }
```

So on javascript you can do like this:

```
 $(function(){
      for(var i = 0; i< $('figcaption'.length; i++){
         $('figcaption').eq(i).addClass('f' + Number(i+1));
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but i didn't get this to work, Chris's answer did work! But thanks for trying <3